# Image processing in apex salesforce

Tags: apex

Is there any way by which apex allows us to process an image, By processing I mean can I read the content of the image if text is available on image using apex .

Answer (score 2):

Apex is not made to do this. Governor limit exists there.

Also images are binary files. Apex has bad support for binary files. If you anyway succeed in reading binary you will see "Apex CPU limit error" very early. If you also overcome with this you will see "heap size limit". So in brief, image processing must not be done with Apex.

Comment: http://processingjs.org/articles/jsQuickStart.html will this help!!

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no image processing library in Apex. I'm afraid you're stuck to using external tools if you want that functionality in Apex